# Swapping from LAN to WLAN upon reaching a certain threshhold

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, batch, lan

**The problem:**

My desktop PC is connected via LAN/Network cable and DLAN (through electric powerline) with the router.

This connection is stable for most of the time, but after a random amount of time, I just get disconnected (still shows connected, but can't do anything online).

That's why I additionally put a WLAN card into my desktop PC.

I swap from LAN to WLAN every time said situation happens. Due to its frequency (4 to 5 times a day) and the fact that I play games most of the time I'm on my PC, this is a pretty time consuming and frustrating solution.

**The question:**

Do you know any software that can swap my connection once a certain download hreshhold is reached (it doesn't automatically swap, as the PC says I'm still connected (see above)).

If not so, is it possible to swap connections through batch? so I just have to click the batch and not through all the Windows menus?

Comment: It sounds like your router is shutting down that port. I had a cable-supplied router/modem that used to do that to the port my switch was connected to once a day. If you can bring the link back up by unplugging the wire from the port and then replugging, this may be the culprit. Everything on the switch could connect to each other, but the link tot he router got blocked. Check intrusion detection and firewall settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is it possible to swap connections through batch?

You can use `netsh` to enable and disable network connections both from the command line and in a batch file.

**enablewifi.cmd**:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" admin=disable
netsh interface set interface "Wireless Network Connection" Enable
```

**enablelan.cmd**:

```
netsh interface set interface "Wireless Network Connection" Disable
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" admin=enable
```

Notes:

- Replace `Local Area Connection` and `Wireless Network Connection` with the interface names of your adapters.
- Use `netsh interface show interface` to get the interface names.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.
- [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx)
- [Netsh Commands for Wireless Local Area Network (WLAN)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
That makes fixing the problem "semi-manually" a lot easier.
Do you know how i could implement this full-automatically once my download rate drops under a threshhold?

Comment: Sorry, no. Otherwise I would have put that in the answer ;)