# Automatic Disconnect of Ethernet When WiFi is enabled

Tags: windows-10, ethernet, automation, connection, adapter

Anytime I enable my wireless network on Win10 the ethernet adapter remains connected.
I would like to set it up such that when a particular interface is selected, the other disconnects. I don't want to manually disable an adapter to perform this.
What is the remedy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Swapping from LAN to WLAN upon reaching a certain threshhold](https://superuser.com/q/1044447)

Comment: Please clarify if it is acceptable for the WLAN adapter to be prioritized, or if the Ethernet adapter should be disabled while WLAN is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Control Panel", go to "Network and Sharing Center" and click on "Change adapter settings." then you will see a list of network adapters. Find the adapter you want to prioritize (e.g., Wi-Fi) and the one you want to automatically disconnect (e.g., Ethernet). Right-click on the adapter you want to prioritize (Wi-Fi) and select "Properties." then in the adapter properties window, click on "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" and then click the "Properties" button.
In the TCP/IPv4 properties window, click the "Advanced" button.
Uncheck the "Automatic metric" option and enter a low numeric value, such as "1," for the adapter you want to prioritize (Wi-Fi).
Click "OK" to close all the properties windows.

Repeat all the process for the adapter you want to automatically disconnect (Ethernet), but set a higher metric, such as "2."

Comment: Disconnecting vis-a-vis an Ethernet connection seems to  imply disabling the connection. Your solution prioritizes traffic to the WiFi adapter. This may be entirely adequate for the OP but the answer would be better if it was clear the distiction and any implications vis-a-vis existing and future conections. For example, will existing connections immediately terminate and "switch" to WIFI?  Will all future connections always default to the adapter with the higher metric? Etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).